# upload to s3 with fileS buffer

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, file-upload, sails.js

I am trying to upload to s3 with bulk files.
Somehow if I am uploading with callback, it'll work properly but I want to push all the return data into an array then do something after.  But it doesn't work.
I looked online, I was saw answers such as using `async await` or `recurssive` would work but still it's not working though.  I even tried using `reduce` but no luck too

example of my `reduce`

```
    return files.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
        const {path, buffer} = current;
        const s3 = new AWS.S3();
        // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property
        s3.putObject(awsS3sdkParams(path, buffer), function ( err, data ) {
            const { protocol, host } = this.request.httpRequest.endpoint;
            data.params = this.request.params;
            data.params.url = `${protocol}//${host}/${data.params.Key}`;
            return [...accumulator, data];
        });
    }, []);
```

example using recurrsive

```
        const result = [];
        const helper = (files) => {
            const {path, buffer} = files[0];
            const s3 = new AWS.S3();
            // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property
            s3.putObject(UploadService.awsS3sdkParams(path, buffer), function (err, data){
                const { protocol, host } = this.request.httpRequest.endpoint;
                data.params = this.request.params;
                data.params.url = `${protocol}//${host}/${data.params.Key}`;
                UtilsService.clDebug(data, 'data');
                result.push(data);
                files.shift();
                if(files.length > 0) return helper(files);
            });
        };

        helper(files);
        return results;
```

example using promise

```
        const result = [];
        for(let {path, buffer} of files){
            const s3 = new AWS.S3();
            s3.putObject(awsS3sdkParams(path, buffer)).promise()
                .then(file => {
                    result.push(file);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err, 'errs');
                });                
        }
```

I can pretty much understand why result is always `[]` but how can I make it work though?
Reason why I cannot use async await is because I tried but then somehow after files are either uploaded with bad data that I cannot even open the file, or keys would be the same...

Does anyone has any other suggestions or advice?

Thanks in advance for any